# Ant assign unique ID to each file

Tags: ant

In an Ant `replaceregexp` task that transforms a directory full of files, I'm inserting IDs in the file contents by using a combination of a timestamp and part of the file contents:

```
<target name="xxx">

  <tstamp>
  <format property="current.time" pattern="hhmmssS" />
  </tstamp>

  <replaceregexp byline="false" flags="gs">
     <regexp pattern="(&lt;body lang=EN-US&gt;)(.*)(&lt;title&gt;(.*)\s(.*)&lt;/title&gt;)"/>
     <substitution expression="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;${line.separator}&lt;!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC &quot;-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN&quot; &quot;concept.dtd&quot;&gt;${line.separator}&lt;concept id=&quot;\5${current.time}&quot;&gt;${line.separator}\3"/>
     <fileset dir="./concept">
     <include name="*.htm"/>
     </fileset>
  </replaceregexp>  

  <var name="current.time" unset="true"/>

</target>
```

The `\5` in the substitution expression is the last word in each file's `<title>` tag. So for example if the file contains `<title>foo bar</title>`, then `\5` = `bar`. So `\5${current.time}` ends up as `bar081853567` or whatever.

This is the closest I am so far to assigning a unique ID inside each file. I'm unsetting the timestamp property (using Ant Contrib) at the end of the target, so other targets in the build will generate a different stamp.

The problem is that within one task, the timestamp property stays the same as it iterates over all the input files, and only unsets when the task is done. If there are two files in the fileset with title tag contents that end in `bar`, then it will assign the same ID for both. Not going to happen often, but sometimes. Duplicate first words are more common, which is why I did it this way.

I'm just wondering what strategies others have used. I was generating a GUID instead of a timestamp, but it's basically the same problem, you can unset the property at the end of the task but it will use the same one for all the files that the task handles.

Answer (score 0):

Split the target `xxx` into two.

```
<target name="xxx-caller">
  <foreach target="xxx-replace" param="file">
    <fileset dir="./concept" casesensitive="yes">
      <include name="**/*.htm"/>
    </fileset>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="xxx-replace">
   <local name="current.time" />
   <tstamp>
      <format property="current.time" pattern="hhmmssS" />
   </tstamp>
  <echo message="inserting id into ${file}"/>
</target>
```